# ZF set theory $\langle 0,1\rangle=?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I'm studying ZF set theory. This is my first exercise, can someone check if it's correct?

$$\begin{align*}
\langle 0,1\rangle &=\{\{0\},\{0,1\}\}\\
&=\{\{\emptyset\} , \{\emptyset\} \cup \{1\}\}\\
&=\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\{\emptyset\}\}\\
&=\{\{\emptyset\} , \{\emptyset\} \cup \{\emptyset\}\}\}\\
&=\{\{\emptyset\} , \{\emptyset\} \}\\
&=\{\{\emptyset\} \}\\
&=\{0 \}=1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{\emptyset\}\}\ne\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: LaTeX/MathJax formatting hint: 'less-than' & 'greater-than' symbols are not a left and right angle bracket. The former two `<0,1>` render as $<0,1>$ while the latter two `\langle 0,1 \rangle` look like $\langle 0,1 \rangle$.

Comment: Your fourth line is certainly wrong; it has unbalanced parentheses, for a start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\{\{\emptyset\}\}\neq \{\emptyset\}$, so your fourth equality is wrong.

Using the Kuratowski definition of ordered pair and von Neumann ordinals, we have $$\langle 0,1\rangle = \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}.$$